# defining an object type that is a subset of another

Tags: typescript, types

I'm having difficulty typing a generic function. The function is given an object, and returns an object containing properties of the given object. So,  a Partial, but the properties are known at compile-time. Here is what I have so far (that doesn't work).

```
type FromFunction = <Input, Keys extends keyof Input>(
  input: Input,
  keys: Array<Keys>
) => {
  [property in Keys]: Input[Keys];
};



export const from: FromFunction = <Input>(input, ...keys) => {
  return keys.map(key => input[key]);
}
```

but when I try to use this, I get this error:

```
// use, which should return { text: 'string' }.
from({ text: 'string', other: 1 }, 'text');

// error
Argument of type '"text"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"text"[]'.ts(2345)
```

Is there a way to do this? I don't want to use `any` or `Partial<Input>`, because the return object is determined at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the keys are known at compile type you probably want to use `Pick`, which allows you to select some properties from a type:

```
type FromFunction = <Input, Keys extends keyof Input>(
    input: Input,
    ...keys: Array<Keys>
) => Pick<Input, Keys>



export const from: FromFunction = <Input, Keys extends keyof Input>(input: Input, ...keys: Keys[]) => {
    // changed the implementation, I think you want to return an object not an array.
    //We can also do tuples (ie arrays) if you want but that is a bit different, let me know if that is what you need.
    var result = {} as Pick<Input, Keys>
    for (let k in keys) {
        result[k] = input[k]
    }
    return result;
}

// use, which should return { text: 'string' }.
from({ text: 'string', other: 1 }, 'text');
```

Comment: Didn't realize there was a built-in type that did this, thanks :) and yes, I realized after posting this that I wanted an object and not an array, so your code is correct.